# Compare 2 text files and display the difference between them (PowerShell or CMD)

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, command

I have 2 text files
`text1.txt` contains:

```
fc1/1 storage
fc1/5 switch
fc1/7 replication
```

`text2.txt` contains:

```
fc1/1 storage
fc1/5 nas
fc1/7 replication
```

I want a script that compares the 2 text files and generate text found on `text2.txt` but not on `text1.txt` in a text file named `difference.txt`

`difference.txt` contains

```
fc1/5 nas
```

any ideas?

Comment: This is what [`Compare-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) is for!

Comment: Downvote "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: I know matt. But my ps script is incomplete. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ...

```
findstr /v /g:text1.txt text2.txt  > difference.txt
```

Search `text2.txt` for lines not matching (`/v`) lines in `text1.txt`